# Existing documents can be found and updated with imported data (using view lookup or database search).

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a list of ID and Color in excel sheet.
I need to import file and check existing if any changes to the color value.
If there is any changes, I need to update new value and recored old value in history field.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, save the Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file, it will be much easier to import it then. Use the file functions in Lotusscript.

Next, write your Lotusscript agent. You have the solution in the headline of your question, so I am not really sure what you are asking.

You could use the GetDocumentByKey() method of the NotesView class to get the document based on the ID, then compare the value of the color field in that document. If it is the same, go to the next document, otherwise add the existing value to teh history field and replace it with the new value, then go to the next document.

Another, and much faster, way would be that you read all the new values into a list, with the ID as list tag and color value as list item. Make sure you have a view with the document ID as one of the columns and color value as another. Create a NotesViewEntryCollection object, then use the GetFirstEntry/GetNextEntry methods to loop through the collection. For each entry, use the ColumnValues() method to get the value if the ID column, and use IsElement to check if that value exists in the list you created. If it does exist, you compare the list item value with the value of the color column. If they are different, open the document, update the history field and replace the old color value with the new value.